# No PID for RabbitMQ

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 and have just installed RabbitMQ using apt.

When I run the init script (as root), I see this:

```
Starting rabbitmq-server: FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log, _err
rabbitmq-server.
```

However if I check the running processes, rabbit is one of them, and startup_log looks fine. But in startup_err:

```
Error: cannot_get_pid
```

Naturally, doing the 'status' and 'stop' commands on the init script don't work either. All of this is as root, by the way. And the running processes are running as the rabbitmq user.

So, somehow the PID isn't being stored anywhere. I'm reasonably new to this, so it's hard for me to tell - where is the PID meant to be stored, and why isn't it being stored there? The init script doesn't reveal a lot to me!

Any help would be awesome - I don't want to do 5 kill commands every time I want to switch off rabbit :) thanks!!
Dan

P.S. this is the log in startup_log. Looks okay to me...

```
node          : rabbit@www
app descriptor: /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-1.7.2/sbin/../ebin/rabbit.app
home dir      : /var/lib/rabbitmq
cookie hash   : KZGa065/Ct5qV2zMWGnEhA==
log           : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit.log
sasl log      : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit-sasl.log
database dir  : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit

starting internal event notification system                           ...done
starting logging server                                               ...done
starting database                                                     ...done
-- kernel ready
starting alarm handler                                                ...done
starting queue supervisor                                             ...done
starting node monitor                                                 ...done
starting cluster router                                               ...done
-- core initialized
starting empty DB check                                               ...done
starting codec correctness check                                      ...done
starting exchange recovery                                            ...done
starting queue recovery                                               ...done
starting persister                                                    ...done
starting guid generator                                               ...done
-- message delivery logic ready
starting error log relay                                              ...done
starting networking                                                   ...done
-- network listeners available

broker running
dan@lennon:/etc
```

Comment: This question should be migrated to [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: when you say you installed it from apt did you install it using from the ubuntu repository or using these instructions http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html? The version in the main Ubuntu repository is quite old so as this is a fresh install I would recommend starting with the latest version.  If you still have the same problem after that let me know

Comment: Rob: I didn't add any repos to my source list so I guess I used the Ubuntu repo. I'll try getting the latest, and if that fails I'll get it from source. If there's any more problems I'll try asking ServerFault as Pedro has suggested. Thanks :)